# Maven just run Integration Tests when call mvn install

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-test

Well, I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.0 with Surefire and Failsafe, so the following plugins:

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- other annotation processors -->
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I have Unit tests (`*Test.java`) and integration tests (`*IT.java`). But running `mvn clean package` just run unit tests, I need run `mvn clean instasll` to run integration tests + unit tests.

Any tips? This is correct?

Comment: mvn package is a phase that is before the integration test phases. see: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html - if you don't want to run install, mvn verify would be the one.

Comment: You usually don't need `install` prefer `mvn verify`...

Comment: Note: [With Java 9+](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-version#java9) you can also use just [`<release>11`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#release) or `<properties>/<maven.compiler.release>11` instead of `source` and `target`.

Comment: Thanks again, i will change.